# How to find values stored in a string not in a sql data table

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example, I have a list of values in a string:

'a', 'c', 'b', 'd'

From the data table, I got a column result like:

```
Result
'a'
'b'
```

how to write a sql which  will return the values not in the table:
'c', 'd'

or

```
NewResult
'c'
'd'
```

?

It is also ok if other simple tools than sql can be used. I only need the result. Thanks!

Comment: What queries have you tried so far? What have you found to work, and what isn't working for you?

Comment: i am stuck with making 'a', 'c', 'b', 'd' to a column. Do I have to create a temp table to do this? Then I have to insert things between 'a', 'c', 'b', 'd'... actually the string is a much more longer string... I read something about pivot/unpivot, but still no clue...

Comment: @vincebowdren so what you think I should try? If there is not other solution, I will write some C# code to do it. but first, I hope sql itself can solve it...

Comment: I think you should search for some sql functions which can do the data manipulation you need, and try them out. Maybe you find a sql tutorial on string variables and functions, and see what you can teach yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Create FUNCTION F_SplitAsTable 
(
@txt varchar(max)
)
RETURNS 
@tab TABLE 
(
 ID Varchar(2000)
)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @i int
    declare @s varchar(2000)
    Set @i = CHARINDEX(',',@txt)
    While @i>1
        begin
          set @s = LEFT(@txt,@i-1)
          insert into @tab (id) values (@s)
          Set @txt=RIGHT(@txt,Len(@txt)-@i)
          Set @i = CHARINDEX(',',@txt)
        end
    insert into @tab (id) values (@txt) 
    RETURN 
END
GO

Declare @a table (Ch varchar(10))
insert into @a Values ('a')
insert into @a Values ('b')


Select s.* from dbo.F_SplitAsTable('a,b,c,d') s
left join @a a on a.Ch=s.ID
where a.Ch is NULL
```

Comment: it works after I changed 'a', 'c', 'b', 'd' to 'a,c,b,d', though I do not know if you can handle 'a', 'c', 'b', 'd' as parameters too :)... thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Load the search values in a temp table.

```
DECLARE @Search table (SearchFor char(1)  not null)

INSERT @Search values ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('d')
```

(There are any number of ways to set this up, this is just the fastest to type)

Run a query like so:

```
SELECT SearchFor
 from @Search
except select SearchIn
 from DataTable
```

(Again, there are many forms that "in a not in b" queries can take.)

This will return everything in the first set (your temp table) that is not also found in the second set.

Comment: is there an easy way to make ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('d') from 'a', 'c', 'b', 'd'?

Answer (score 1):

use the `not in` clause in your queries.

```
select myCol from myTable where myCol not in ('c','d')
select myCol from myTable where myCol not in (select myCol from otherTable)
```

Comment: These will not provide the desired answer.

Comment: Yes, sadly someone sent me a string... not something like myCol... but thanks anyway

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous, so it's hard to tell right now.

Comment: Can't you just treat the string as a CSV, and import it into your database?  Then the query would work.

Comment: The second would work if "otherTable" was a temp table populated by a split of the string inserted into a column by that name in that temp table

Comment: Maybe it was not the desired answer, but it was mine, so thank you Michael!